# Magento 2.1.6 - Extending the dropdownDialog (lib/web/mage/dropdown.js) not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, drop-downs, ui-library

I am trying to extend the default dropdown.js of Magento

1) Created a new JS file at `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme-name>/web/js/mage/dropdown.js`

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/dropdown"
], function($){
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.customdropdownDialog', $.mage.dropdownDialog, {
        _create: function() {
            this._super();
            console.log("Testing...");
        },
    });

    return $.mage.customdropdownDialog;
});
```

2) Added reference in the `requirejs-config.js` at `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme-name>/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "dropdownDialog": "js/mage/dropdown"
        }
    }
};
```

3) Ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

I keep getting the following error whenever I try to click on any dropdown created using the dropdown.js libary.

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dropdownDialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: update to latest version should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue multiple times, and fixed it by the next way:
So, the problem is in line 64 of file `lib\web\mage\dropdown.js`

```
 $('.' + _self.options.defaultDialogClass + ' > .ui-dialog-content').dropdownDialog("close");
```

I think it's needed for closing any other dropdowns before open current dropdown.
The problem is that we can use dropdown methods only with the same jQuery objects they were initialized. But jQuery object `$('.' + _self.options.defaultDialogClass + ' > .ui-dialog-content')` is new and nothing has been initialized with it. 
Possible solution is to use the custom event to properly close the dropdowns without recreating new jQuery objects. For example:

```
_create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.uiDialog.addClass(this.options.defaultDialogClass);
    var _self = this;

    $(document).on('custom.dropdownOpened', $.proxy(_self.close, _self));

    if (_self.options.triggerTarget) {
        $(_self.options.triggerTarget).on(_self.options.triggerEvent,function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(!_self._isOpen) {
                $(document).trigger('custom.dropdownOpened');
                _self.open();
            }
            else {
                _self.close(event);
            }
        });
   }

    if (_self.options.shadowHinter) {
        _self.hinter = $('<div class="' + _self.options.shadowHinter + '"/>');
        _self.element.append(_self.hinter);
    }
},
```

So, instead of using "close method" on new object, we trigger a custom event, and handle the widget's method "close" on it. In this case for every dropdown the correct method "close" with the proper scope will be exectuted. 
The **bad thing** about this solution is that we need to override the entire $.mage.dropdownDialog widget and extend $.ui.dialog widget instead. 
Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of this line in the original widget:

```
$('.' + _self.options.defaultDialogClass + ' > .ui-dialog-content').dropdownDialog('close');
```

This is calling the `dropdownDialog` widget which we have overridden. In your case you've overridden with `customdropdownDialog` which is the widget that will get instantiated on the elements. In other words, the error is right: `dropdownDialog` has not been intialiazed, because `customdropdownDialog` has been intialized instead.

So the call to interact with that instatiated widget should now be:

```
$('.' + _self.options.defaultDialogClass + ' > .ui-dialog-content').customdropdownDialog('close');
```

In order to deal with this, you'll need to take control of the event listener that powers the interaction with the dropdown widget. Based on the code you posted, it would be something like this:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/dropdown"
], function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.customdropdownDialog', $.mage.dropdownDialog, {
        _create: function() {
            this._super();
            console.log("Testing...");

            if (_self.options.triggerTarget) {
                $(_self.options.triggerTarget).off(_self.options.triggerEvent); // remove original event, created by parent ($.mage.dropdownDialog)

                // recreate the event listener, changing only the call to other dropdowns
                $(_self.options.triggerTarget).on(_self.options.triggerEvent, function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    if (!_self._isOpen) {
                        $('.' + _self.options.defaultDialogClass + ' > .ui-dialog-content').customdropdownDialog('close');
                        _self.open();
                    } else {
                        _self.close(event);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return $.mage.customdropdownDialog;

});
```